# Cannot find PGXS for Postgresql 8.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, unaccent

I am trying to install the contrib/unaccent package for Postgresql 8.4 on my Ubuntu box. But I got the error message when I typed make:

> /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory

Apparently PGXS is Postgresql's infrastructure for installing extensions, but I could not find the file pgxs.mk at all on my ubuntu box.

Following some leads on the Internet, I tried installing libpq-dev. Nonetheless, I couldn't find any pgxs.mk even after installing libpq-dev.

What's really frustrating is that I can't even find an example of pgxs.mk anywhere on the Internet. How do I install the PGXS infrastructure?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146279/error-installing-postgis-on-debian/26266796

Answer (score 17):

Probably you need to install [`postgresql-server-dev-8.4`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/postgresql-server-dev-8.4) package, which [contains](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/postgresql-server-dev-8.4/filelist) your missing makefile:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
```

Comment: I confirm that this worked with Ubuntu maverick ( 10.10 ) i686.