# Error "the PGXS Makefile cannot be found" when installing PostGis on Debian

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I am in the process of installing PostGis over psql on a Debian machine (actually crunchbang).

I have completed the following steps:

```
$ wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.3.tar.gz
$ tar xzf postgis-2.0.3.tar.gz
$ cd postgis-2.0.3
$ ./configure
```

On the final step I get the following error:

```
configure: error: the PGXS Makefile /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk cannot be found. Please install the PostgreSQL server development packages and re-run configure.
```

The issue is that I do already have Postgres installed:

```
$ psql --version
psql (9.1.9)
```

I have checked this on two machines with the same configuration and get the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Here are some useful instructions: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Debian70src

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL is broken down into several packages, and having `psql` installed doesn't imply that the development packages are also installed.

According to the error message:

> Please install the PostgreSQL server development packages and re-run
>   configure

you need:

```
# apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

Also note there's a [APT pgdg repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)  providing recent pre-compiled versions of postgres-related packages (including postgis) that you may use instead of self-compiling.

If your system is set up to use this repository, just do:

```
# apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0
```

Comment: there's a ```postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1``` now. How I wish I knew the existence of this repo sooner :/

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer works great except that it needs the following update:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.1
```

These packages can be updated some time in future again. So, it is recommended to search for new packages using aptitude and install the appropriate one:

```
$ aptitude search postgis
```